# Grouping Exposed Filters (using Better Exposed Filters)

Tags: views

We have a view using [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) called Programs with an exposed filter on a taxonomy term "Level of Study". I'd like to group this so that the only values in the exposed filters are **Graduate** and **Undergraduate**.

I first tried to "group" the terms as follows

[image]

but then got errors as follows:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in views_many_to_one_helper->ensure_my_table() (line 954 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/handlers.inc).
```

[image]

I then tried to rearrange the taxonomy so that Graduate and Undergradute terms are parent to the others as follows:

```
Graduate
- MFA Degrees    
- Professional Degrees    
- Doctoral Degrees    

Undergraduate    
- Majors and Minors    
- Modules    
- Interdisciplinary Programs
```

And this still does not yield the desired result.

So I'm at a loss and opening up a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'd recommend adding a taxonomy term 'Graduate Interdisciplinary Program' to match the 'Undergraduate Interdisciplinary Program'

[image: Configure your vocaulary]

Assuming you have these taxonomy terms 'weighted' to their respective parent terms 'Graduate' and 'Undergraduate' you can proceed to configure your view.

[image: Your views page - you'll need to configure fields and filters as you like]

Configure the filter criteria as follows:

> **Settings**
>
> Content:Has Taxonomy Terms
>
> Vocabulary: Graduate/Undergraduate Programs
>
> Selection Type: Dropdown
>
> Depth: 1

[image: Views Settings]

> **Configure Filter Criteria**
>
> Tick - Expose this filter to Visitors, to allow them to change it.
>
> Tick - Grouped Filters
>
> Widget Type - Select List
>
> Label - 'Area of Study'

[image: Views Settings]

Finally configure the table as you have it in your screen-shot ... ideally without the overlap of the term 'Multidisciplinary Program' ...

[image: Table]

Comment: Can you include any screen shots or urls? I'm looking to get a defacto, how-to answer!

Comment: @Richard - yes...

Comment: Brilliant and well worth the bounty. Many, many thanks!