# Grouping Exposed Filters

Tags: views

I am working with the module Better Exposed Filters (BEF) within my view. I have about 12 exposed filters, some of theme are select lists and some are range sliders. Some filters thematically belong together which is why I try to visually group them under a headline. Unfortunately, this can't be done using BEF.

I also tried Views Exposed Groups but this module can only be used instead of BEF, not together (I need BEF because of the slider funcionality). Besides I tried MEFIBS (More Exposed Filters in Blocks) which isn't suitable for me too.

Does somebody know of another module that helps me to accomplish this problem?

PS: I am no coder so editing the exposed-form.tpl.php is the last option for me.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Try this answer:

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118626/grouping-exposed-filters-using-better-exposed-filters

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw this question. It is not what I am looking for. Grouping filters in views is not supposed to visually group exposed filters.

Answer (score 0):

if you get the filter slider effect how you want save the view and disable the BEF module then go back to the view it can work. I remember I tried something like this before. It might break if you go back and mess with the filter and not just grouping.

Comment: Although this would not have been a perfect solution I gave it a shot and it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: ah. Sorry I thought it worked for me once.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Views Exposed Form Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ef_fieldset) module?  It has releases for both Drupal 7 and 8.